# How to Use couchDB as local storage in android application

Tags: database, sqlite, couchdb

I am developing an app, which is in android. 
In my app I want to use couchdb database for storing and sync purpose.
which will work offline too.

so, how to create couchDB database first and then insert data in that database, so that my application will use the couchDB database as local storage like SQLite. 
I have aleready went through many links but they are not satisfying my need.
So Please provide some guide line or an help or comment or sample code to performed that operation.

Answer (score 3):

CouchDb and Couchbase Lite are very close in terms of usage. If you are looking for an easy way to sync and store data locally on your android device I would recommend looking at Couchbase Lite for Android.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android